# Как определить размер базы данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть ли способ узнать подробную информацию о базе данных, используя **PHP** или **MySQL** запрос? Интересуют базовая инфа, Размер БД, количество записей, возможная нагрузка на ресурсы ПК.

Необходимо вычислить примерный КФ, исходя из которого можно было бы принять решение - очистить БД. Т.к. данные мусорные и используются только для анализа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Размер

```
  SELECT table_schema "database_name", sum( data_length + index_length )/1024/1024 "Data Base Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Источник http://skeletor.org.ua/?p=1966

Количество записей по таблицам хранится в этой же таблице (TABLES), столбец TABLE_ROWS

Основную информацию по базе, таблицам в этой базе можно получить исходя из данных в этой таблице, основные столбци, которые могут быть Вам интересны:

- TABLE_SCHEMA - Имя базы данных
- TABLE_NAME - Имя таблици
- TABLE_ROWS - количество записей
- DATA_LENGTH - размер данных в байтах
- INDEX_LENGTH - размер индексов в байтах

Comment: И вот первая проблема. Размер БД не изменяется с увеличением строк например с 2000000, по 2240000.. Это что? Как работает эта функция, если в начале дня размер БД был 140,67 Мб, и в конце дня я записал чертову дюжину записей в БД и размер так и остался 140,67. СУБД резервирует место на диске с приличным запасом или как?

Comment: Все зависит от конфигурации mysql-сервера, например для innodb есть параметр конфиграциии AUTOEXTEND SIZE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-resize-system-tablespace.html , так же после удаления большого обьема данных рекомендуется отимизировать таблицу (OPTIMIZE TABLE) http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/OPTIMIZE_TABLE.html Собственно для полного понимания почему не изменятся размер БД - нужно детально разобраться в собсвенной конфигурации сервера БД